# Eucalyptus OSG not configured and S3 url not set

Tags: cloud, centos6, eucalyptus, walrus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcZCY.png)During configuration of a private eucalyptus cloud on centos6 the following warn is coming on running the command source eucarc :

WARN: An OSG is either not registered or not configured. S3_URL is not set. Please register an OSG and/or set a valid s3 endpoint and download credentials again. Or set S3_URL manually to http://OSG-IP:8773/services/objectstorage

The OSG is set to use Walrus.
Even though the OSG is enabled state. The eucalyptus console is also not showing on the host ip.

we have two machines one hosts the NC and the other hosts the CC SC Walrus CLC.

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the WARN line in the `eucarc` file with the IP address of the host where User Facing Services is installed,

e.g if it's a all-in-one system then IP of this machine, or if it's only one frontend and one node controller, mostly like it will be the IP address of your Frontend where all the services are installed.

So, in this case, edit the WARN line in eucarc file with something like this:

```
export S3_URL=http://192.168.14.148:8773/services/objectstorage
```

Comment: It gave me warning "warn: export S3_URL=http://192.168.14.148:8773/services/objectstorage" and UI didn't worked again same error

Comment: Make sure you don't have any thing in front of ``export S3_URL``.